# Isn't that ungrammatical?

Tags: grammar

The Reverend said I was to go back to my cot and I was not to eat supper for a week.
**Which** I didn't eat supper anyway.

from "The Education of Little Tree 영한대역 p594"

If "which" is a relative pronoun, isn't it ungrammatical to follow it with a complete sentence?

Comment: It's okay in conversation, but not correct written English. "Which I didn't eat anyway" is correct -- not a full sentence, but a logical thought.

Comment: @Yosef Baskin - Thank you for the reply.

Comment: "Which" used to be used at the beginning of a sentence as a meaningless 'filler', in the same way that people today use "So".

Comment: @Kate Bunting - Ah, I see, thank you for the information.

Comment: Dialog in fiction represents spoken speech, not formal writing. Some books represent characters whose speech diverges widely from academically accepted usage, like the works of Mark Twain or Charles Dickens. I'm guessing that the speaker here, besides speaking colloquially, is a child. Note that this particular book [is not what it claims to be, and comes with controversy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Education_of_Little_Tree).

Comment: No, it is not okay by any standard. Which I didn't eat anyway. is the spoken language here.  It is not a mistake a native speaker would make. Very unlikely. It could also have said: I didn't eat supper anyway. There are dialects and mistakes. This is a mistake.

Comment: HOWEVER: a small child might make that mistake.

Comment: @Andy Bonner, Lambie - Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, it is ungrammatical.

However, being a quote, and thus representational of the character's spoken word, it may be assumed that the *character* made the mistake in speaking.

Even in fiction this may be done to indicate colloquial use within the context of the story, or a lack of education on the part of the character, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.